# Under which assumptions does weak stationarity imply strong stationarity

Tags: time-series, self-study, stationarity

An excercise question for time series analysis asks:

Consider the process
$$
y_t = 0.8y_{t-1} + 0.1y_{t-2} + u_t
$$

1. Is this process weakly stationary (I would answer this with the stability triangle)
2. Under which assumptions does this property imply strong stationarity

I thought that strong stationarity always implies weak stationarity, but not that it can be the other way around.

Comment: Either a "$+$" or a "$-$" is missing in your process. Can you please edit it? Thanks!

Comment: Stong stationarity does not imply weak stationarity. Hint: does weak stationarity require existence of the first two moments? And does strong stationarity have anything to tell about that?

Comment: True, strong stationarity only implies weak stationarity, if the first two moments also exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: consider what happens when you make more assumptions about the specific distribution of the errors. Then you can write down exact conditional densities. After multiplying a few together, you will have the joint density of all the time observations, and strong stationarity deals with this joint distribution.

For your model:
$$
p(y_1, y_2, \ldots , y_n) = \prod_{t=3}^n p(y_t \mid y_{t-1}, y_{t-2} ) p(y_1, y_2)\tag{1}.
$$
If you assumed that the errors were Normally distributed then
$$
 p(y_t \mid y_{t-1}, y_{t-2} ) = N(.8 y_{t-1} +.1 y_{t-2}, \sigma^2).
$$

Another hint:
If this Normal distribution does lead to strong stationarity, then the 
joint distribution of all the observations $\{y_t\}$ should have the right means, and the right variances and (auto-)covariances. Arrange all of those autocovariances and variances into a matrix $\Gamma$. Then your joint density should be 
$$
(2\pi)^{-n/2}(\det\Gamma)^{-1/2}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{y}_t'\Gamma^{-1}\mathbf{y}_t \right].
$$

Comment: Sorry, I dont get what exactly you mean

Comment: Does the edit help?

Comment: Mh, I guess you say, that the process ist stationary, if the errors are normally distributed. But I can't see, how that comes out of the definition of the strong stationarity (sorry for asking probably trivial questions, we never did a lot with this).

Comment: @LucaThiede it's not trivial. I just don't want to spoil the fun for you.

Comment: Isn't strong stationarity defined over the cumulative distribution? How is the autocovariance helping right now?

Comment: @LucaThiede that's one way of defining it. You can always integrate this density if you want the cdf. There's no loss of generality

Comment: I still dont see, how this relates to the autocorrelation though

Comment: @LucaThiede the $(i,j)$ element of $\Gamma$ is the autocovariance at lag $i-j$.

Comment: Mh, so we have now a formula for p(x_1,..,x_n), and it has the strong stationarity property, when this equals p(x_(1+k),...,x_(nk)) for all k and all n. And since this formula does not change when we substitute t with t+k this proofs strong stationarity?

Comment: @LucaThiede yes

Comment: I have one last question: We assumed for this only, that the error is from a normal distribution, but dont usually assume this for an ARIMA model, so why is this an addtional assumption?

Comment: @LucaThiede strong stationarity is a statement about distributions. Weak stationarity only deals with moments. When moments exist they are only summaries of a distribution. you need to assume something about the distributions or else you just can't get where you want to go.